# Add Multiple LinearLayout inside of another LinearLayout is not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout which should contains a list of items (each item is a LinearLayout). 
 The problem is that the childs items (LinearLayouts) are not displayed one below another: just the fist one is visible.

This is my layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label_TextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/form_label_padding_left"
    android:text="" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/form_list_holder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/form_list_background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_TextView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/form_label_padding_left"
            android:text="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtx_input1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/form_input_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_edittext_margin_top"
            android:layout_weight="5" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtx_remark1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/form_input_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_edittext_margin_top"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:hint="@string/remarks"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_TextView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/form_label_padding_left"
            android:text="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtx_input2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/form_input_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_edittext_margin_top"
            android:layout_weight="5" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtx_remark2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/form_input_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_edittext_margin_top"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:hint="@string/remarks"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Do you know why this is happen? I thought that in a LinearLayout if there is not more available space on current line, the childs will be displayed on the next line.

Comment: change orientation to vertical

Comment: and set **android:weightsum** for parent to apply **layout_weight**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `LinearLayout` whose id is `form_list_holder` has a `android:orientation="horizontal"`.

The orientation should be Vertical instead usign `android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Linear layout within RelativeLayout. so that you can set the

```
android:layout_below="@+id/above_layout" //above_layout is the id of previous layout


<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layout1"
      android:layout_width="Wrap_Content"
      android:layout_height="Wrap_Content">

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layout2"
      android:layout_width="Wrap_Content"
      android:layout_height="Wrap_Content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/layout1">

    </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layout3"
      android:layout_width="Wrap_Content"
      android:layout_height="Wrap_Content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/layout2">

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It may helpful to you..

Comment: I can't use the RelativeLayout because all my layouts are added dinamically so if I use the linearlayout, these layouts will be displayed one below another without adding any rule as I will have to do when if I will use RelativeLayout. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have set all your android:layout_width="0dp", meaning you wont be able to see anything. Change 0dp to match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/form_list_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/form_list_background" >

    <TextView
          android:id="@+id/label_TextView"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/form_label_padding_left"
          android:text="" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_TextView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/form_label_padding_left"
            android:text="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtx_input1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/form_input_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_edittext_margin_top"
            android:layout_weight="5" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtx_remark1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/form_input_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_edittext_margin_top"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:hint="@string/remarks"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_TextView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/form_label_padding_left"
            android:text="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtx_input2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/form_input_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_edittext_margin_top"
            android:layout_weight="5" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtx_remark2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/form_input_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/form_edittext_margin_top"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:hint="@string/remarks"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```